# How to compare the elements of a list to a 2-dimensional list (without using a huge amount of if/elif/else statements)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to learn how to take two lists, compare them to one another, and then edit one or both of the lists depending on the values in the elements of the two list.

For example, some psuedo code:

```
ARRAY = [['1', '2'],
         ['3', '4']]
USER_MADE_ARRAY = input('type in numbers.')
#print(USER_MADE_ARRAY)
#>>>['1', '3', '2']

#if USER_MADE_ARRAY == the value of any of the elements in ARRAY[row 0]:
#   USER_MADE_ARRAY[elements equal to the values in ARRAY[row 0]] = "Bob"
#print(USER_MADE_ARRAY)

#>>>['Bob', '3', 'Bob']

#And so on...
```

I just don't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
user_made_array = ["Bob" if item in array[0] else item for item in user_made_array]
```

(the uppercase was a bit wearing...)

Without much more information it's hard to see how to generalise this; it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. However, you could do something like:

```
replace = {'1': 'Bob', '2': 'Bob'}

user_made_array = [replace.get(item, item) for item in user_made_array]
```

If you have a list of words the same length as `array`, you can build `replace` with `zip`:

```
names = ['Bob', 'Colin']

replace = {}
for name, nums in zip(names, array):
    replace.update({num: name for num in nums})
```

But this is really just guessing, because you haven't included much information in your question.

Comment: I have a lot of questions.  How did you know to do that?  I know what functions you are using, but how did you look at the problem and just used them in that way?  What is that 'item' doing?  What is going on in this code?

Comment: To be more specific, The '["Bob" if item in array[0]' sorta makes sense, but how does python know that 'item' is the numbers 1 and 2?  'else item for item in user_made_array' makes less sense

Comment: @user3513276: Click on the link at the top of the answer to read about list comprehensions. The syntax is `[expression for item in iterable]` where `iterable` is your existing iterable object (like a list), `item` is the name of a variable that is created while iterating on it and `expression` is some expression that probably uses `item` in some way to create values for the new list.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The example you provided was very helpful, once I read about list comprehensions.  
One thing I noticed, though is that list comprehensions don't seem to allow elif or any additional if statements.  Is there a way of using these statements in a single line?

Comment: @user3513276 that would make for (even more) unreadable list comprehensions. What's the `elif` case, are you trying to replace e.g. `array[0]` elements with `"Bob"`, `array[1]` elements with, erm, `"Colin"`, etc.?

Comment: Well the way I did it in the end was:

I'm half-remembering this, but the way I was told is that there is a 'better' way to compare and edit arrays than just using {for x in y: for x in b: if x is c: do this}, over and over again.   Something about using a constant array to do make it 'better'.

Comment: @user3513276 I would make a dictionary `d = {old: new, ...}`, then your code is `[d.get(item, item) for item in ...]`